# Passing userInfo (NSDictionary) to another object with NSNotication

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary, nsnotifications

I'm trying to use NSNotification.  I create a NSDictionary based on which of my buttons was pressed in a view.  When I NSLog the tag, the tag is correct.  So I use a switch statement like this in order to create my dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dict;
switch (tag) {
    case 0:
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tag] forKey:@"ButtonType"];
        break;
    case 1:
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tag], @"ButtonType", nil];
        break;
    case 2:
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tag], @"ButtonType", nil];
        break;
    case 3:
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tag], @"ButtonType", nil];
        break;
    case 4:
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tag], @"ButtonType", nil];
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"No dictionary set for ButtonType");
        break;
}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:(ShowData:) object:self userInfo:dict];
```

And then in ShowData:

```
- (void)ShowData:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    NSDictionary *userDict = [notification userInfo];
    NSInteger theTag = (NSInteger)[userDict objectForKey:@"ButtonType"];
    NSLog(@"tag: %i", theTag); // this value is incorrect
```

In my ShowData method, I'd expect the same tag values, 0-4, but instead I get stuff like: 187742848.  When I step through the debugger, I see my NSDictionary userInfo being set to the value that is passed.  Am I not creating my NSDictionary correct to pass to ShowData:?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of casting the object returned from the dictionary, call `integerValue`.

```
[[userDict objectForKey:@"ButtonType"] integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I couldn't cast NSNumber to NSInteger.  I needed to use integerValue from NSNumber and I got the correct tag value.